# What are all these symbols in letters in quelltext from social media in the place of HTML tags?

Tags: html

when I create websites and check its quelltext what I see is the HTML tags and links I've created, but many sites has these letters and symbols instead, such as social media ones. Could you explain what they are?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are HTML Entities.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)

> Entities are frequently used to display reserved characters (which would otherwise be interpreted as HTML code), and invisible characters (like non-breaking spaces). You can also use them in place of other characters that are difficult to type with a standard keyboard.

Doing this adds some assurance that the code will be parsed correctly by most if not all engines it may encounter.

For example, `&quot;` is used to represent a quotation mark `"`.